# Get common value among Datatable rows

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable like this:

```
| Supplier  | Product | Price | NewPrice | Category | Quality |
|-----------|---------|-------|----------|----------|---------|
| Supplier1 | Orange  | 100   | 105      | Food     | Good    |
| Supplier2 | Orange  | 110   | 130      | Food     | Good    |
| Supplier3 | Orange  | 200   | 250      | Food     | Good    |
```

I need a new DataRow with common values of each column

```
| Supplier  | Product | Price | NewPrice | Category | Quality |
|-----------|---------|-------|----------|----------|---------|
| Supplier1 | Orange  | 100   | 105      | Food     | Good    |
| Supplier2 | Orange  | 110   | 130      | Food     | Good    |
| Supplier3 | Orange  | 200   | 250      | Food     | Good    |
|-----------|---------|-------|----------|----------|---------|
|           | Orange  |       |          | Food     | Good    |
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how you store your datatables, but using linq it can be done as follows:

You need to first add a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and `System.linq`

```
var count = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r[0]).Where(gr => gr.Count() == dt.AsEnumerable().Count()).Count();
object result;
if (count == 1)
    result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r[0]).Where(gr => gr.Count() == dt.AsEnumerable().Count()).First().Key;
else
    result = "";        //or null, depending on what you need
```

`result` shows the value appearing in all rows of the 0th column, otherwise it is an empty string. For example, in your case using `r[1]` instead of `r[0]` will show result as `Orange`.

Rename `dt` with your datatable's name and try it out. I check the count first to make sure there are no exceptions with sequence empty.

I did not come up with this logic myself, took reference from this answer:
[How to find duplicate record using Linq from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941058/6741868)

Explanation:

First use `GroupBy()` on your column values of all rows to **group them by same values**. Then check if the **count** of each of them is equal to the **total row count**, which is equivalent to checking if the value appears in all rows. If that succeeds, we find your value, otherwise set result to **empty string**, or **null**.