# calculating the occurrence of two column values in DataTable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, count, group-by

I have a data table, which contains set of Attributes like (First Name, Last Name, Gender etc..)
I wanna count the occurrence of value in only two columns or Attribute.

For example, I have 4 columns in my datatable (FirstName, LastName, Age, Gender).

I want to know if any two or more records in the datatable shares the same first name and last name.

I have no idea where to start, any idea can save my day

thank you

Comment: It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939516/how-to-find-duplicate-record-using-linq-from-datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use LINQ(-To-DataTable).

Group by an anonympous type containing both properties:

```
var duplicates = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { 
        FirstName = r.Field<string>("First Name"),
        LastName  = r.Field<string>("Last Name")
    })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => new { Person = g.Key, Count = g.Count(), Rows = g.ToList() });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var duplicates = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r[0]).Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1);
```

dt is datatable.