# Checking a DataTable Column for Uniqueness

Tags: c#, datatable

This method below of determining whether a column in DataTable seems very slow. Is there any suggestion of a quicker way of checking a particular column for uniqueness, perhaps without having to create a separate view?

```
var view = new DataView(LoadedDataTable);
var distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, ColID);
if (distinctValues.Rows.Count != LoadedDataTable.Rows.Count)
    Messagebox.Show("Column " + ColID + " is not unique.");
```

**update**

One thing that may be useful to note is that I don't care about finding the duplicates, just whether the column is unique or not. I.e. if it finds a duplicate it could stop searching. If that makes any difference!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939516/how-to-find-duplicate-record-using-linq-from-datatable

Comment: You can try LINQ as suggested, but judging from your code, you may just be dealing with a very large amount of data that takes time to process.  It's also possible that ToTable(bool, string) is taking time, which is why I didn't suggest just casting the view to two one-column tables (one non-unique) and testing to see if the two tables themselves are equal.

Comment: @CDove I appreciate your suggestion, it is likely the size of the table columns wise that is delaying the `ToTable()`. I feel like Blake's answer below is essentially doing as you suggest, using Linq to process just the single column on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick time test for me had this solution as significantly faster (about 10 ms vs 1000 ms) than using a DataView and ToTable with about 15000 rows in the table.

```
var values = LoadedDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => r[ColID])
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
var unique = values.Count == LoadedDataTable.Rows.Count;
```