# VB.Net - Efficient way of de-duplicating data

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, ienumerable, deduplication

I am dealing with a legacy application which is written in VB.Net 2.0 against a SQL 2000 database.

There is a single table which has ~125,000 rows and 2 pairs of fields with similar data.

i.e. FieldA1, FieldB1, FieldA2, FieldB2

I need to process a combined, distinct list of FieldA, FieldB.

Using SQL I have confirmed that there are ~140,000 distinct rows.

Due to a very restrictive framework in the application I can only retrieve the data as either 2 XML objects, 2 DataTable objects or 2 DataTableReader objects. I am unable to execute custom SQL using the framework.

Due to a very restrictive DB access policy I am unable to add a View or Stored Proc to retrieve as a single list.

What is the most efficient way to combine the 2 XML / DataTable / DataTableReader objects into a single, distinct, IEnumerable object for later processing?

Answer (score 1):

I may have missed something here but could you not combine both DataTables [using Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx)?

```
DataTableA.Merge(DataTableB)
```

You can then use `DataTableA.AsEnumerable()`

Then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415519/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-data-table) on how to remove duplicates or

You can do this with a `DataView` as follows: `dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True,[Column names])`

Comment: That does combine the 2 but there are duplicates

Comment: The DataView method works perfectly with 5000 records on our DEV db but is taking a very long time to process on our TST db with 140,000 records

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with.

Combine the 2 DataTables using `.Merge` (thanks to Matt's answer)

Using [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326176) as a base I came up with the following code to get distinct rows from the DataTable based on 2 columns:

```
Private Shared Function GetDistinctRows(sourceTable As DataTable, ParamArray columnNames As String()) As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sort = String.Empty

    For Each columnName As String In columnNames

        dt.Columns.Add(columnName, sourceTable.Columns(columnName).DataType)

        If sort.Length > 0 Then
            sort = sort & ","
        End If

        sort = sort & columnName

    Next

    Dim lastValue As DataRow = Nothing

    For Each dr As DataRow In sourceTable.Select("", sort)

        Dim add As Boolean = False

        If IsNothing(lastValue) Then
            add = True
        Else
            For Each columnName As String In columnNames
                If Not (lastValue(columnName).Equals(dr(columnName))) Then
                    add = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If add Then
            lastValue = dr
            dt.ImportRow(dr)
        End If

    Next

    Return dt

End Function
```