# Table doesn't have primary key c#

Tags: c#, datatable

Im trying to delete rows from `DataTable AllItems` with rows from `DataTables Items`; The purpose of this to get items from `DataTable AllItems` which are not inside `DataTable Items`

**All these rows Fiiled from same Excel file which contains several columns and are equal.**

I have tried using foreach loop:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in AllItems.Rows)
{
if (Items.Contains(dr))
{
AllItems.Rows.Remove(dr);
}
```

But I get following error: Table doesn't have primary key.

Does anyone knows how i can delete these rows?

Comment: It's [best](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx) to use lowercase-first camel-case for `variableNames`.

Comment: Vote to Close (spotted after adding an answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415519/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-data-table - in particular, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15264638/1073107 gives a very succint answer for removing duplicate rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few choices here:

**1. Add a Primary Key**

you can add a [primary key to your data table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z24kefs8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when creating it.

Assuming you had a column called "Id" then you would do it this way:

```
AllItems.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { workTable.Columns["Id"] };}
```

Or, for cases where your primary key is a composite key (multiple columns):

```
AllItems.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
                             workTable.Columns["Id"], 
                             workTable.Columns["Name"] };}
```

This would then allow Contains to work correctly.

**2. Use a DataView**

You can use a DataView to filter out the distinct rows;

```
DataView view = new DataView(AllItems);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" , ..., "ColumnN");
```

**3. Find Matching Rows using Select**

Or you can rely on the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method to test if a corresponding row exists in the `Items` DataTable based on a statement that's like a SQL WHEREclause:

```
List<DataRow> rowsToRemove = new List<DataRow>();

foreach(DataRow allItemRow in AllItems.Rows)
{
    if(Items.Select(String.Format("Id = {0}"), 
          allItemRow.Field<Int32>("Id")).Length == 0)
    {
        rowsToRemove.Add(allItemRow);
    }
}

rowsToRemove.ForEach(x => x.Delete());

AllItems.AcceptChanges();
```

**Note** that it's important NOT to remove rows while you are iterating the collection of Rows in AllItems - instead, collect these rows, and remove them afterwards.

**4. Filter on the way in**

Also note, and I haven't tried it, but, depending on how you are selecting the rows out of Excel, you may be able to use the SQL DISTINCT clause; if you are using [ODBC to load data from Excel](http://www.microsoft-csharp-tutorials.com/post/2013/02/20/Connect-to-Excel-using-ODBC-in-C) then you could try filtering at source.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
var exceptItems = AllItems.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Except(Items.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), DataRowComparer.Default)
    .ToList();
```

As an alternative, if you want to keep working with the `allItems` data table after removing the `items` rows from it, you may try this (assuming that you have the column `Id` in both data tables, which uniquely identifies a row per data table):

```
var exceptItems = AllItems.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select((i, index) => new { id = i["Id"], index })
    .Intersect(Items.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .Select((i, index) => new { id = i["Id"], index }))
    .ToList();

for (int i = exceptItems.Count()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    AllItems.Rows.RemoveAt(exceptItems[i].index);
}
```

Here's a nicer arrangement of the last example above:

```
AllItems.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select((i, index) => new { id = i["Id"], index })
    .Intersect(Items.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .Select((i, index) => new { id = i["Id"], index }))
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.index)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => AllItems.Rows.RemoveAt(i.index));
```

Comment: It doesn't remove rows after excetuing this AllItems.Count is the same

Comment: You may work with `exceptItems`.

Comment: I've added two alternatives of removing the `Items` rows from the `AllItems` table. These will only work if you have a common `Id` column which identifies the rows.