# how to pass values from ListView to Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview

I am using Visual Basic 2008. I have a ListView and a DataGridView which have both 3 columns like ProductCode, ProductName & ProductPrice. Now I want to pass ListView values to DataGridView in the same sequence. I want that when I double click on any row in the ListView these row values inserted to DataGridView.

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick 
    If Not ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 
         '// check if item is selected. 
        With ListView1.SelectedItems(0) 
            Dim lvItem() As String = {.Text, .SubItems(1).Text, .SubItems(2).Text} 
            '// get ListView selectedItem. 
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(lvItem) '// add it to DataGridView. 
        End With 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: databound datagridview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will work

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick 
    If Not ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 
         '// check if item is selected. 
        With ListView1.SelectedItems(0) 
            Dim lvItem() As String = {.Text, .SubItems(1).Text, .SubItems(2).Text} 
            '// get ListView selectedItem. 

            'Assumed that TableDGV as your DGV datasource

            TableDGV.Rows.Add(lvItem) '// add it to DataGridView. 
            DataGridView1.DataSource = TableDGV


        End With 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks mat your code is working but how to avoid duplicate values pass in datagridview say if product already exist in datagridview it show me message product already in gridview do u want to replace if i click replace product will replaced

Comment: @zahidmahmood .. if this help, you may vote this as the answer .. and to avoid duplicate you can see this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415519/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-data-table

Answer (score 0):

You should check the event when clicked the listview, and on that event create something that edite the datagridview :)

Comment: but showing following error msg
"Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

Comment: @zahidmahmood .. you cant add row in databound DGV .. you should add to your DGV datasource --> datatable

Comment: Please Give Me Any Example Add DGV Datasource Datatable

Comment: @zahidmahmood .. Find something like 'Add row to table' ... Google will help you ..

Comment: An answer like this is more properly a comment, IMO.