# How can I set value in combo-box But no-Repeat c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel sheet and I want to fetch some data from excel to c# but the data I have is repeated in some columns.

I need select this data in combo-box but no-repeat

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT  TL From [Data$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "TL";
```

Please help me with this code,

Thanks for all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove duplicate entries from a data table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415519/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-data-table)

Comment: @Mohamed, Have you tried this "SELECT DISTINCT TL From [Data$]". Might it will help you.

Comment: @Govind Parmar Very Thanks My Pro For helping Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'DISTINCT' command in SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TL From [Data$]
```