# how to show two tables of dataset in gridview and show same row of two tables in single row in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

here dataset has two tables(table,table1).both have some common fields and common data. while I am binding these two tables into gridview, it shows two rows.
I want to bind in single row,like:https://forums.asp.net/t/1963338.aspx?how+to+merge+two+different+rows+of+datatable+into+single+row+in+same+datatable.

Comment: Can you please show your code ?

Comment: DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                dt2 = ds.Tables[1];
                DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
                dt3 = dt1.Copy();
                dt3.Merge(dt2, false);
                grdVehicleUtilization.DataSource = dt3;
                grdVehicleUtilization.DataBind();

Comment: Copy dt1 to dt2 , Search and remove duplicate records from dt2 and then assign it to DataSource. check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415519/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-data-table

Answer (score 0):

i just  created temp(dt4) table. and added required fields from two tables. and finaly   binded temp table to grdview.`

```
                if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        d4.Rows.Add(dt1.Rows[i][0], dt1.Rows[i][1], dt1.Rows[i][2], dt1.Rows[i][3], dt1.Rows[i][4], dt2.Rows[i][3]);

                        grdVehicleUtilization.DataSource = d4;
                        grdVehicleUtilization.DataBind();
                    }

                }`
```