# DataTable only removes one row?

Tags: c#, datatable

Can somebody tell me my mistake?
I have two Tables, merged in one. They are distinguishable by one column called source. (expected, found)
I wan´t to remove all equal rows...
But in case of removing both rows, only the row `i-1` will be removed...

```
for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (tbl.Rows[i].ItemArray.Contains(Constants.VALUE_SOURCE_FOUND) && tbl.Rows[i - 1].ItemArray.Contains(Constants.VALUE_SOURCE_EXPECTED))
                    {

                        var founded = (tbl.Rows[i].ItemArray).ToArray();
                        var expected = (tbl.Rows[i - 1].ItemArray).ToArray();


                        for (int u = 0; u < founded.Length; u++)
                        {
                            if (founded[u].ToString() == Constants.VALUE_SOURCE_FOUND)
                            {
                                founded = founded.Where(w => w != founded[u]).ToArray();        
                                expected = expected.Where(w => w != expected[u]).ToArray();     
                            }
                        }


                        if (founded.ToString() == expected.ToString())
                        {
                            tbl.Rows[i - 1].Delete();       
                            tbl.AcceptChanges();
                            tbl.Rows[i].Delete();           
                            tbl.AcceptChanges();
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }


        return tbl;
```

Comment: You should rather tell us why you think that there is something wrong in that piece of code

Comment: :) `tbl` returns a Table for a DataGrid. The code removes all the right rows from `i-1`, but shows the `i` rows...

Comment: If you remove `i-1`, then what was at `i` before is now at `i-1`

Comment: @steve16351 you mean I have to remove `i-1` two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
tbl.Rows[i].Delete();
tbl.AcceptChanges();

tbl.Rows[i-1].Delete();

tbl.AcceptChanges();

i = i - 2;
```

As far as i know, delete only "marks" the row as to be deleted, you have to commit it first. With your second call you commit the first one, but the second delete is never executed on the datatable.

Comment: If it would: please add some explanation such that the OP can learn from it

Comment: now it deletes every secound simmular row :D wtf
i´ve edited my code, can u have a look?

Comment: Maybe this would be a better solution for you alltogether:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415519/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-data-table

Comment: @goetterkomplex nope, I already tryed everything from this side but thx